# BibLaTeX doesn't work anymore

Tags: biblatex

I reinstalled MiKTeX and now I can't make bibliographies anymore. I have a file called `a.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{b}

\begin{document}
\cite{a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and `b.bib` containing

```
@book{a,
    title={a},
    author={a}
}
```

Even after compiling multiple times with LaTeX and biber, there is no bibliography and it says that the citation is undefined. Am I missing something? Why doesn't it work? I installed the latest updates in the MiKTeX console.

Comment: Make sure that your really call Biber on your document/that your editor really runs Biber on your document (check with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). If you ran the complete LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle there should be a `.blg` file (on Windows that file may mistakenly be classified as "performance monitor file", but it is a text file you can open with any text editor), please add the complete contents of your `.blg` file to your question.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. It actually works now. The default bibliography tool was indeed set to bibtex. But I still find it weird because I could make bibliographies with BibLaTeX using bibtex before. I also tried compiling on the console with biber and it had the same error messages. I don't have the old `.blg` file anymore.

Comment: If you load `biblatex` with `backend=biber,` you *must* compile the document with Biber. It is possible that your editor is (or was) configured to run Biber when you click on a button that says "BibTeX", but that doesn't change the fact that only Biber can be used. A Biber run can only be successful after a successful LaTeX run (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). If something is wrong Biber should tell you about it directly when you run it from the command line.

Comment: @moewe Maybe that's what happened. But since it works now, I'm happy, so thanks.